# Installing latest drupal console RC via composer

Tags: composer, console

I'm trying to install drupal console latest release candidate globally via composer. I run

```
$ composer global require drupal/console:~1.0.0@rc
```

But I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc9 requires drupal/console-core ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc8 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc7 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc6 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc5 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc4 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc3 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0@RC -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc2 requires drupal/console-core ^1.0@RC -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc16 requires drupal/console-core 1.0.0-rc16 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc16] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc15 requires drupal/console-core 1.0.0-rc15 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc15] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc14 requires drupal/console-core 1.0.0-rc14 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc14] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc13 requires drupal/console-core 1.0.0-rc13 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc13] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc12 requires drupal/console-core 1.0.0-rc12 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc12] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc11 requires drupal/console-core ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc10 requires drupal/console-core ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/console 1.0.0-rc1 requires drupal/console-core ~1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc9, v1.0.0-rc8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Removal request for drupal/console == 1.0.0.0-beta5
    - Installation request for drupal/console ~1.0.0@rc -> satisfiable by drupal/console[1.0.0-rc1, 1.0.0-rc10, 1.0.0-rc11, 1.0.0-rc12, 1.0.0-rc13, 1.0.0-rc14, 1.0.0-rc15, 1.0.0-rc16, 1.0.0-rc2, 1.0.0-rc3, 1.0.0-rc4, 1.0.0-rc5, 1.0.0-rc6, 1.0.0-rc7, 1.0.0-rc8, 1.0.0-rc9, 1.0.0-beta5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

When I run:

```
$ composer global require drupal/console:~1.0.0@dev
```

It installs beta5.

P.S. I don't want to edit composer.json, it will be an automated script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that Drupal console's dependent packages (`drupal/console-core`, `drupal/console-en`) didn't use the `minimum-stability` option that I specified via `@`, so I just had to set it globally and run again:

```
$ composer global config minimum-stability rc
$ composer global require drupal/console:1.*
```